# MPI proceso master se congela

Tags: c, mpi

tengo este código sin terminar pero para ir comprobando que todo funciona voy compilando y probando. El caso es el procesador 0 se congela al terminar el primer for y no pasa de ahi, ni siquiera se ejecuta la parte del segundo procesador (lo estoy ejecutando con dos).

```c
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
srand(time(NULL));

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Status stat;

int NUM_CLIENTES = atoi(argv[1]);
int *ingresos=calloc(NUM_CLIENTES,sizeof(int));
int *gastos=calloc(NUM_CLIENTES,sizeof(int));

int modulo = NUM_CLIENTES%size;
int division = NUM_CLIENTES/size;

if(rank==MASTER_ID){
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_CLIENTES;i++){
        ingresos[i] = rand()%9999;
        gastos[i] = rand()%9999;
        printf("yes:%d \n",NUM_CLIENTES);
    }
    printf("skere :%d",1);
    int maloc = division;
    int* send = malloc(sizeof(int)*maloc);
    int count = division;
    for(int i = 1;i < size;i++){

        if(modulo!=0 && i==size-1 ){
            send = malloc(sizeof(int)*(maloc+modulo));
            maloc = size*division+modulo;
            count = division+modulo;
        }else{
            maloc = division*(i+1);
            count = division;
        }

        for(int j = i*division,k=0;j < maloc;j++,k++){
            send[k]=ingresos[j];
        }

        MPI_Send(&send,count,MPI_INT,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<maloc;i++){
        send[i]=ingresos[i];
    }

}
if(rank!=MASTER_ID){
    printf("recivo :%d",1);
    int maloc=0;
    if( (modulo != 0) && (rank==(size-1)) )
        maloc = division+modulo;
    else
        maloc = division;

    int* recv = malloc(sizeof(int)*maloc);
    MPI_Recv(&recv,maloc,MPI_INT,rank,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);

}
MPI_Finalize();
exit(0);
};
```

Nunca llega a mostrar la línea de "skere", pero los yes si. El printf de recibo tampoco se ejecuta, se queda congelado. Si lo ejecuto con un solo procesador funciona perfectamente.

Comment: okey, no habia visto que estaba intentando recibir un mensaje del mismo procesador,mb

Comment: Que es MASTER_ID y rank? Deberías poner todo el código necesario , para tu problema, y que no aparezcan el codigo cosas que no estan definidas o codigo oculto. Ya que no somos adivinos.